# Torch Resize Tensor

Tags: lua, machine-learning, resize, torch

How do I resize a Tensor in Torch? Methods documented in https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#resizing do not seem to work.

```
images = image.load('image.png',1,'float')
print(images:size()) 
-- result: 224x224 [torch.LongStorage of size 2] 

images.resize(torch.FloatTensor(224,224,1,1))
print(images:size()) 
-- result: 224x224 [torch.LongStorage of size 2] 
-- expected: 224x224x1x1 [torch.LongStorage of size 4]
```

Why doesn't this approach work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do:

```
images:resize(...)
```

What you did:

```
images.resize(...)
```

images.resize does not pass the current tensor as the first argument.

`images:resize(...)` is equivalent to `images.resize(images, ...)`